# How to view image in image box just after the user has selected an image in file upload in code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My html code is this

```html
                <asp:Image ID="Img_CreateUser" runat="server"/>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload_CreateUser" runat="server" />
```

My C# code is this

```
        byte[] ImgArr = null;

        if(Upload_CreateUser.PostedFile != null)
        {
            HttpPostedFile File = (HttpPostedFile)Upload_CreateUser.PostedFile;

            string Filename = Path.GetFileName(Upload_CreateUser.FileName);
            Upload_CreateUser.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + Filename);

            //byte[] filebytes = Upload_CreateUser.FileBytes;

            using(FileStream filestream = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                ImgArr = new byte[filestream.Length];
                int ImgReadArr = filestream.Read(ImgArr, 0, (int)filestream.Length);

                if(ImgArr != null && ImgArr.Length > 0)
                {
                    string ImgType = File.ContentType;
                    string base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(ImgArr, 0, ImgArr.Length);
                    Img_CreateUser.ImageUrl = "data:" +ImgType+ ";base64," + base64string;
                }
```

`
I dont want to save my image into database. I just want to preview it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>       
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head runat="server">  

  <title>Preview Image While Upload</title>       
    <script src="jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function ShowPreview(input) {  
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {  
                var ImageDir = new FileReader();  
                ImageDir.onload = function(e) {  
                    $('#impPrev').attr('src', e.target.result);  
                }  
                ImageDir.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);  
            }  
        }  
    </script>

</head>  
<body>  
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="4" width="70%" align="center" style="border: Solid 10px Green;  
        font-weight: bold; font-size: 16pt; background-color: Skyblue; color: Blue;">  
        <tr>  
            <td align="center">  
                Upload Images  
            </td>  
        </tr>  
        <tr>     

         <td>  
                Select Your File To Upload #:  
                <input type="file" name="ImageUpload" id="ImageUpload" onchange="ShowPreview(this)" />  
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" />  
            </td>  
        </tr>  
        <tr>  
            <td>  
                <asp:Image ID="impPrev" runat="server" Height="200px" />  
            </td>  
        </tr>  
    </table>  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

For more details Go through the link it will help you

[Preview Image Before Uploading](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/preview-image-before-upload-using-jquery-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: It is using jquery. i want it to be done by code behind.

Comment: you can't do it in code behind directly and it's not a good practice to do it in code behind. if you really want to do it in code behind you can add all the jquery code in a string and bind that string to the image box.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function previewFile() {
                var preview = document.querySelector('#<%=ImgPropertyGroupImageAdd.ClientID %>');
                var file = document.querySelector('#<%=InputPropertyGroupImageAdd.ClientID %>').files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    preview.src = reader.result;
                }

                if (file) {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                } else {
                    preview.src = "";
                }
            }
        </script>

<asp:Image ID="ImgPropertyGroupImageAdd" runat="server"  Width="200px" Height="200px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Open.png" />
<asp:FileUpload ID="InputPropertyGroupImageAdd" type="file"  onchange="previewFile()"  runat="server" />
```